# UI performance penalty when using UIAutomation

Tags: ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using UIAutomation and precisely UIAComWrapper from [UI Automation COM-to-.NET Adapter](https://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/).

I am trying to scrape the contents of the target Window and it works but I noticed a problem.

When I access the target window the screen refreshing on the window slows down. It looks like the UIAutomation is interfering with the target window. Is it possible ? Or maybe the slowness has another reason ?

Comment: It can be possible of course but it may be an indirect cause, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091769/ui-performance-penalty-when-using-uiautoamtion

Comment: @SimonMourier: Was there a reason you linked back to this very question in your comment?

Comment: I messed things up apparently :-) here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716078/wpf-performance-issue-due-to-ui-automation

Comment: I am not sure but I suspect the UIAutomation client somehow injects in the target process and searches the tree. I think it is possible because I tried to scrap FLASH objects running in Chrome browser and it works. When I tried to scan every 50 ms the FLASH refresh rate and playback decreased visibly.